# Centered divs with overall border

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkbynkmf/1/

How do I let the green border flow around all the divs, with no div "overflowing" the border? The upper div is OK, but the lower one is not.
Also, I need some distance between the divs;

I know that padding and margin is transparent, so I chose (a green) border to illustrate my point. In the end, the clearance should be transparent.

HTML:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px solid #190;
  margin: 0px; 
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;                 /* div will be     H-centered */
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;  
  overflow: hidden;              /* Keep all sub-elements inside this div */
}

#intro {
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;                 /* div will be H-centered */
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;              /* Keep all sub-elements inside this div */
}
```

```html
<body>                        <!--position: relative;-->
    <div id="header">         <!--position: relative;-->            
    </div>
    <div id="intro">          <!--position: relative;-->            
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: add `padding-bottom: 15px;` to the body element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `top` attribute to move your intro `div` 15px down, below the header. This is causing the 15px overlap with the container. When positioning items this way you should consider using `margin` to apply the change, rather than the positioning attributes of `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`.

You have a lot going on with your CSS which is making the stylesheet much more complicated than it needs to be. I have simplified your CSS as follows to achieve the same effect:

```
body { 
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border: 10px solid #190;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a img {
    border:none;
}

#header {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;  
    height: 250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}

#intro {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    margin:15px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkbynkmf/18/)

Comment: Thank you - I tried to circumvent the overlap of the second div by assigning posisition "relative" to the the body and the divs; obviously incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `#intro` is positioned 15px below the `#header`. Doing so leaves no place for the div in body.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here with `position: relative;` but the `#intro` can be written like

```
#intro
{   
    margin:10px auto;/* div will be H-centered */

    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;/* Keep all sub-elements inside this div */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the margin top property on the #intro div will allow the green border to flow, while also having the space in between the divs. Here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hkbynkmf/17/

```
#intro
{
    position: relative;
    margin:15px auto 0px auto                               /* div will be H-centered */

    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;                                   /* Keep all sub-elements inside this div */
}
```